# Java compiler generates Incompatible error when passing generic parameter to a method

Tags: java

I have class structures like this:

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

public interface MyTypeIfc {
}

public class TypeOf<T extends MyTypeIfc> {
}

public class BaseType<T> {
    public void write(String fieldName, T value) {
        System.out.println(fieldName + value.toString());
    }
}

public class MyTypeClass<T extends MyTypeIfc> extends BaseType<TypeOf<T>> {
    public void write(TypeOf<T> value) {
        System.out.println(value.toString());
    }
}

public class Main {
    private static final MyTypeClass<? extends MyInterface> myType = new MyTypeClass<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        myType.write("fieldName", getNodeType());  <-- This line gives incompatible error
    }

    private TypeOf<? extends MyInterface> getNodeType() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the line marked above, I get an incompatible error:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] ....Main.java:[12,46] incompatible types: com.type.TypeOf<capture#1 of ? extends com.type.MyInterface> cannot be converted to com.type.TypeOf<capture#2 of ? extends com.type.MyInterface>
```

It seems Java does not allow me to pass `TypeOf<? extends MyInterface>` object as an parameter to a method that accepts `TypeOf<? extends MyInterface>`.

Can someone please help me understand why?

Comment: `myType` could be `MyTypeClass<Foo>`, `getNodeType()` could be `TypeOf<Bar>`. The compiler can't guarantee they're the same.

Comment: Notice the `capture#1` and the `capture#2`.  What if `myType` was a `MyTypeClass<Cheese>`, and `Cheese` extends `MyInterface`, but `getNodeType` returns a `TypeOf<Apple>`, and `Apple` also extends `MyInterface`.  Do you still think they would be compatible?